# How do I contact Xbox Live Account staff via e-Mail?

Tags: xbox-network

I was looking for a really old account of mine on Xbox live and I found it; it has been about 7 years since it's been used and has become inactive.

Now I cannot remember any info needed to access that account, but I want to email someone who handles things like this at Xbox live headquarters. The only options their xbox.com site is giving is to call them or have them call you, but no email.

I find emailing so much easier and a lot cheaper too.
Does anyone know where i can find an email address to use 
or a decent site that will put me into the right direction?

Is there any way of getting through to them without phoning?

Comment: The contact options they present to you depends on what issue you choose. Generally, inquiries on an account must be done over the phone or live chat with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get in contact with Microsoft personnel in the [official forum](http://forums.xbox.com/xbox_forums/xbox_support/default.aspx).

But i think this is going to be a lost cause.
If the account has been inactive for 7 years straight, then it is most likely not inactive, but deleted due to a timout.
And seeing as the XBL service as a whole only exists for 10 years now, it actually more than just "most likely" that your account is deleted.

But still, try and you might get lucky.